# Is there a way to have a program find the next available row in a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I create a program that sorts through a spreadsheet finds the last line of data then copies/pastes in new text in the next available row?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: And does your data have blanks, or is it contiguous?

Comment: This question has already been answered: A quick search of StackOverFlow for "vba excel find last row" gives this nice solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092329/find-bottom-of-excel-worksheet-in-vba

Comment: The data does have blanks, however column A is always populated. So I was thinking of having a program search through each row and just column A to find a blank. Once a blank is found, then it can paste in the new data.

Comment: The link provided by Jon49 includes a reference for sparse data.

Comment: Thanks everyone, This is the code that I ended up using after looking at the references.

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

Comment: You dont need to select cells to work with them.  Your method is good for finding the last used cell in a column. For a better method of finding the actual last used cell take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423022/excel-getting-the-actual-usedrange/7427466#comment-8980597

Answer (score 0):

This UDF receive a Sheet name at first parameter, and a column letter to find a row, this return a next line available.

```
Function GetLin(Sht As String, Col As String)
'officevb.com
Dim UltLinPlan As Long

'Get a last row in sheet
UltLinPlan = Sheets(Sht).Range("A65536").End(xlDown).Row

'Return this number
GetLin = Sheets(Sht).Range(Col & UltLinPlan).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

End Function
```

To use is very simple

```
dim x as long

x=GetLin("Sheet1","A")
```

This sample returns a next line in column A from Sheet1

[]'s

Comment: Replace Range("A65536") with Cells(Rows.Count,1) to be Excel version agnostic, since 65536 is no longer the last row in Excel 2007 and later.

Comment: Ronnie, this version work´s in Office 2007/2010. Verify this line ´UltLinPlan = Sheets(Sht).Range("A65536").End(xlDown).Row´ , the direction is down!

Comment: It should be xlUp.  This is a standard Excel practice - find the last row, and mimic CTRL+ up arrow to then find the last row.  Things will work without my commented change if you have < 65,536 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Bruno's method will not work in later versions of Excel if you have data in `Column A` after `Row 65536`. Additionally, if you have data at the end of the sheet (regardless of version), if you do `xlUp`, then you'll skip past the true end.

This method relies on the popular method with a quick check for the very last row.

```
Sub getlin2()

Dim lin As Long
Dim Sht As String
Dim Col As String

Col = "A"
Sht = "Sheet1"

lin = Sheets(Sht).Rows.Count
If Sheets(Sht).Range(Col & lin).Value = vbNullString Then
    lin = Sheets(Sht).Range(Col & Sheets(Sht).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End If

MsgBox lin

End Sub
```